# In a div, i want 1 item to be left aligned and the other right aligned

Tags: css

I have 2 elements:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

and i wanted to make `a` align left and `b` to align right.  Normally im used to leveraging float, but i wanted it to fit within the confines of the parent object for cleanliness.

Im trying to get A and B be clean and line up horizonally while 1 is on 1 size of the div.

I was trying various attempts of display:inline-block and then doing a flight right  etc but that isnt getting the desired effect.

**EDIT**  It seems that generally speaking, float right and left were working.  The issue is that the bottom alignment is off which was annoying me.

If i am incorporating a float right and float left, it works based on the element, but if there a way to line it up so that both A and B are resting on the bottom of the parent?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. It seems you want A and B to be of equal width and height relative to the parent.

Comment: do you mean http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pyWJRL ?

Comment: @GCyrillus yeah, this is what i want i think.  The text inside of A and B are aligned with the bottom, instead of normal Top.

Comment: maybe a screenshot of what you really would help you. I might update my answer below if we have a better understanding of what you try to get :) your html is just empty of content ....

Comment: @GCyrillus after looking at your example, your implementation is exactly what i am looking for

Comment: okay then upvote or accept answer :) or both . glad i helped anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you considered flex ?

```css
#parent {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
div {
  margin:auto 0 0;/* they line up from bottom in this margin case */
  border:solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b<br/>line</div>
</div>
```

or

```css
#parent {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
div {
  border:solid;
  /* no rules about behaviior makes each boxes of a row same height */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b<br/>line</div>
</div>
```

now question doesn't say about size (width/height) of boxes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="a" style="float: left;">Hello</div>
  <div id="b" style="float: right;">World!</div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Need something in the middle of it?

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="a" style="float: left;">Hello</div>
  <div id="b" style="float: right;">World!</div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">holy schmoley</div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

All together now.

```
<style type="text/css">
#a {
    float: left;
}

#b {
    float: right;
}

#c {
    text-align: center;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="a">Hello</div>
  <div id="b">World!</div>
  <div id="c">holy schmoley</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

---

Of equal heights:

```
<style type="text/css">
#a, #b, #c {
    height: 100%;
}

#a {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    float: left;
}

#b {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    float: right;
}

#c {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    text-align: center;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="a">Hello</div>
  <div id="b">World!</div>
  <div id="c">holy schmoley</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

---

Aligned to the bottom using absolute, I recommend adding a margin to the #c div to prevent any odd overlapping:

```
<style type="text/css">
#parent {
    position: relative;
}

#a, #b {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}


#a {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

#b {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    right: 0;
}

#c {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    text-align: center;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="a">Hello</div>
  <div id="b">World!</div>
  <div id="c">holy schmoley<br /><br /><br /></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Float with Flex**

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    /* width: 600px; */
}

#parent {
    position: relative;
}

#a {
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

#b {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

#c {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}

#d {
    padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
    width: inherit;
}

#e {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
</style>


<div id="container">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="a">
            <div id="b">Hello</div>
            <div id="c">
                World!
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="d">
            <div id="e">
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Heres my content!!<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
&copy Copyright
```

Float with flex, bottom positioning:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    /* width: 600px; */
}

#parent {
    position: relative;
}

#a {
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#b {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

#c {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}

#d {
    padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
    width: inherit;
}

#e {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
</style>


<div id="container">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="a">
            <div id="b">Hello</div>
            <div id="c">
                World!
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="d">
            <div id="e">
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Heres my content!!<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
&copy Copyright
```

---

Using the flex float bottom as your full page layout:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
}

#parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#a {
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#b {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#c {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}

#d {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

#e {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="a">
            <div id="b">Hello</div>
            <div id="c">
                World!
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="d">
            <div id="e">
                Heres my content!!<br /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, if this were the case, how would i line up the bottom of them.

Comment: Are you trying to make them all the same height or align the boxes in their current height to the bottom of the parent box?

Comment: A and B are of different heights.

Comment: Try my last example, float with flex, to get three boxes where the boxes on the sides are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option (based off your new criteria)

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#a, #b {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kkpw9pqw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
div#a{text-align:left;}
div#b{text-align:right;}
```

Or *vice-versa* will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `float` then you can use `display: table;` to achieve the desired effect. But this will need an additional wrapper.

CSS

```
#wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#parent {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
#a {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}

#b {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="a">AAAA</div>
    <div id="b">BBBBB<p>
    asdfafasfasdf
    </p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nLg0wwo/) .

Answer (score 0):

give 50% width to each div a and b and then make a float:left and b float:right . 
and give equal height to both divs a and b .
try it

```
    <div id="parent">
   <div id="a">div a</div>
   <div id="b">div b</div>
     </div> 
   #a {

  background:red;
  float:right;
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
}

    #b {
 width:50%;
  background:green;
   float:left;
   height:200px;}
```

[image: example]